# Groovy & SoapUI - NumberFormatException

Tags: groovy, soapui, numberformatexception

In SoapUI I am able to get a response from a web service that gives me a string return.

```
XML Node                     Value
soap:Envelope                           {Envelope}
  soap:Body                             {Body}
    EuroConvertorResponse
      EuroConvertorResult    1.0966     {xsd:string}
```

I manage to read the response in Groovy script but I get number format exception.  My code is:

```
String conversionString = context.expand( 
'${EuroConvertorRequest#Response#declare namespace 
ns1=\'http://tempuri.org/\'; //ns1:EuroConvertorResponse[1]}' )

double convertedRate = Double.parseDouble(conversionString);
```

The exact error I get is:

> *java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "   1.0966   " error at line: 10*.

If I hard code the response like below it works fine though!

```
String conversionRate = "1.0966";
double convertedRate = Double.parseDouble(conversionString);
```

Any idea?

Comment: maybe you have spaces in string? try to do `Double.parseDouble(conversionString.trim())`.

Comment: Dragonfly, please check the solution and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes!! Result I needed. Thanks loads @Rao!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using incorrect `xpath`, I believe. Supposed to query for `EuroConvertorResult`, not `EuroConvertorResponse`.

Try changing from:

```
String conversionString = context.expand('${EuroConvertorRequest#Response#declare namespace ns1=\'http://tempuri.org/\'; //ns1:EuroConvertorResponse[1]}' )
```

To:

```
String conversionString = context.expand('${EuroConvertorRequest#Response#declare namespace ns1=\'http://tempuri.org/\'; //ns1:EuroConvertorResult}' )
```

Or in fact, get the double value in single line itself by coercing as below, by adding `as Double` at the end:

```
def conversionResult = context.expand('${EuroConvertorRequest#Response#declare namespace ns1=\'http://tempuri.org/\'; //ns1:EuroConvertorResult}' ) as Double
assert conversionResult instanceof Double
```

Alternatively, you can use `XmlSlurper` to achieve the same:

```
def result = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.expand('${EuroConvertorRequest#Response}').'**'.find{it.name() == 'EuroConvertorResult'}.text() as Double
log.info result
assert result instanceof Double
```

Comment: Hi @Rao, I am experimenting and thought I'd try your last solution of XmlSlurper but I get error "No such property: **for class:java.lang.String"  I am using a different web service but same concept.  Any idea?

Comment: My XML is: <GetCityWeatherResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <GetCityWeatherResult>
            <CityInfo><![CDATA[<coord lon="-1.84" lat="37.21"></coord><country>ES</country><sun rise="2017-08-19T05:27:33" set="2017-08-19T18:53:31"></sun>]]></CityInfo>
            <Clouds>few clouds</Clouds>
            <Weather>few clouds</Weather>
            <Temperature>302.15</Temperature>
         </GetCityWeatherResult>
     </GetCityWeatherResponse>

Comment: I also try this: def xml = context.expand( '${CityWeatherRequest#Response#declare namespace ns1=\'http://tempuri.org/\'; //ns1:GetCityWeatherResponse[1]}' )
def result = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
log.info("Result: " + result.Clouds) ... and while I get response in result i get nothing in the log, i.e. result.Clouds returning blank :S

Comment: Actually I changed approach and used XmlHolder with getNode.  Worked fine to get Weather, Clouds, Temperature.  Was unable to get coord, country, sun rise though.  I did 
def xml = context.expand( '${CityWeatherRequest#Response#declare namespace ns1=\'http://tempuri.org/\'; //ns1:GetCityWeatherResponse[1]}' )
def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(xml)
def weather = holder.getNodeValues("//*:GetCityWeatherResponse/*:GetCityWeatherResult/*:Weather") as String